# Align text beside a div

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to create clickable words inside a text. Each time the user clicks on a word, a window opens up underneath it.

Here is an example:  [image]

My problem is every clickable word is not aligned with the text (line breaks, misalignment, etc) as you can see in the photo.

```html
<p>Salut, Welcome,  Bienvenue chez  
  <div class="jargon-item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-model="collapsed1" ng-click="collapsed1=!collapsed1"> R2A</a>...
    <div class="boxed" ng-show="collapsed1">Rhone-Alpes Auvergne</div>
  </div>
</p>
```

It is happening because it is how  works, but I cannot change that because i need the window to be exactly under the word.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not wrap `div`'s using `p`. Instead use a `div` to wrap other `div`'s

1. Adding `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` will modify the default display property of `div`.
2. Use `position: relative` to the parent and `position: absolute` to the child `.boxed`

**Note**: By default `div`'s are displayed as **block**.

---

**Update:** I have hidden the text by default, it will be visible when you hover on the link.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper div.boxed {
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: palegreen;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid forestgreen;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.jargon-item a:hover + .boxed {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  Salut, Welcome, Bienvenue chez
  <div class="jargon-item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-model="collapsed1" ng-click="collapsed1=!collapsed1">R2A</a>...
    <div class="boxed" ng-show="collapsed1">Rhone-Alpes Auvergne</div>
  </div>
  Some more text here. You can add more text if you want. You can also include another link here.
  <div class="jargon-item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-model="collapsed1" ng-click="collapsed1=!collapsed1">Click me</a>...
    <div class="boxed" ng-show="collapsed1">I added this !</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  Salut, Welcome, Bienvenue chez
  <div class="jargon-item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-model="collapsed1" ng-click="collapsed1=!collapsed1">R2A</a>...
    <div class="boxed" ng-show="collapsed1">Rhone-Alpes Auvergne</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not what i want to do. The elements in "boxed" class should stay below the words as in the picture. But the problem is that "R2A" should be in the same line as "chez". it is the same sentence

Comment: When i add a similar paragraph below it it does not work :/

Comment: @Hana : Check the updated answer. I have hidden the text by default. it will be displayed when hovered

Answer (score -1):

Apply float:left to every element.